# Summarising from one table into another with a couple of steps

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to summarise some  as shown below:

| Date_Start | Date_End | Counter_val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10/01/2020 | 12/01/2020 | 1 |
| 08/01/2020 | 09/01/2020 | 1 |
| 27/03/2020 | 03/04/2020 | 1 |
| 12/02/2020 | 16/02/2020 | 1 |
| 18/02/2020 | 20/02/2020 | 1 |
| 01/01/2020 | 08/01/2020 | 1 |
| 30/12/2019 | 07/01/2020 | 1 |
| 01/01/2020 | 11/01/2020 | 1 |

The summary table is shown below:

| Week_From | Week_To | Week_Date | Total_Cases |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 13/01/2020 |  |
| 1 | 3 | 13/01/2020 |  |
| 3 | 2000 | 13/01/2020 |  |
| 0 | 1 | 12/04/2020 |  |
| 1 | 3 | 12/04/2020 |  |
| 3 | 2000 | 12/04/2020 |  |

The first step for each row is to use only rows from the data table where the date_end is earlier than the week_date in the summary table.

For example, when using 13/1/2020 in the summary table, there are 5 rows where the date_end is earlier in the data table.

I then need to group the data by the difference in weeks between the week_date field int eh summary table and the date_start field in the data table.

For example, there are two rows in the data table where the date_end field is earlier than 13/1/20 and the difference in weeks between 13/1/20 and the start date is less than 1.

To create the data tables, try:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST.DBO.TBL_CASES 
(
    Date_Start DATE,
    Date_End DATE,
    Counter_val FLOAT
);

INSERT INTO TEST.DBO.TBL_CASES (Date_Start,Date_End,Counter_val)
VALUES  (cast('1/1/2020' as date), cast('01/28/2020' as date), 1),
        (cast('1/1/2020' as date), cast('01/09/2020' as date), 1),
        (cast('1/1/2020' as date), cast('04/03/2020' as date), 1),
        (cast('1/1/2020' as date), cast('02/16/2020' as date), 1),
        (cast('1/1/2020' as date), cast('02/20/2020' as date), 1),
        (cast('1/1/2020' as date), cast('01/08/2020' as date), 1),
        (cast('1/1/2020' as date), cast('01/07/2020' as date), 1),
        (cast('1/1/2020' as date), cast('01/11/2020' as date), 1);

CREATE TABLE TEST.DBO.TBL_TOTALS 
(
    Week_From FLOAT,
    Week_To FLOAT,
    Week_Date DATE,
    Total_Cases FLOAT
);

INSERT INTO TEST.DBO.TBL_TOTALS (Week_From, Week_To, Week_Date, Total_Cases)
VALUES  (0, 1, cast('1/13/2020' as date), 0),
        (1, 3, cast('1/13/2020' as date), 0),
        (3, 2000, cast('1/13/2020' as date), 0),
        (0, 1, cast('4/12/2020' as date), 0),
        (1, 3, cast('4/12/2020' as date), 0),
        (3, 2000, cast('4/12/2020' as date), 0);
```

I have tried the following but get an error:

```
DECLARE @var_week_in_question DATE
DECLARE @var_date_start DATE
DECLARE @var_date_end DATE
DECLARE @var_week_total float
DECLARE @var_Week_From float
DECLARE @var_Week_to Float

UPDATE TEST.DBO.TBL_TOTALS
UPDATE TEST.DBO.TBL_CASES
SET @week_in_question = TEST.DBO.TBL_TOTALS.Week_Date,
    @var_date_start = TEST.DBO.TBL_CASES.Date_start,
    @var_date_end = TEST.DBO.TBL_CASES.Date_end,
    @var_Week_From = TEST.DBO.TBL_TOTALS.Week_From,
    @var_Week_To = TEST.DBO.TBL_TOTALS.Week_To,
    @var_week_total = TEST.DBO.TBL_TOTALS.Total_Cases = (SELECT SUM(TEST.DBO.TBL_CASES.Counter_val)
                                                         FROM TEST.DBO.TBL_CASES
                                                         WHERE (@var_date_end < @week_in_question)
                                                           AND (DATEDIFF(week, @week_in_question, @var_date_start) > @var_Week_From)
                                                           AND (DATEDIFF(week, @week_in_question, @var_Date_start) <= @var_Week_To))
```

Any assistance would be most appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You don't say what "what error" but I can see your SQL is invalid, you have two rogue `update` statements that should not be there and your `set` should be `select`; you don't seem to be joining your two tables in any meaningful way.

Comment: Hi Stu, You're right about the rogue statements. However, I think I need a different approach as everything I try just doesn't work. Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work out the answer to this. I did it by creating a temporary table with all the permutations of the data table and the date from the summary table.

The only problem is that that the temporary when I use the real data (rather than the test data shown above) is 33 million records which makes it rather cumbersome.

Code used as follows:

```
-- Part 1 - create merged table
SELECT DISTINCT dbo.TBL_CASES.Date_Start, dbo.TBL_CASES.Date_End, dbo.TBL_CASES.Counter_val, dbo.TBL_CASES.[w/c], dbo.TBL_TOTALS.Week_Date
INTO test.dbo.merged
FROM   dbo.TBL_CASES CROSS JOIN
             dbo.TBL_TOTALS

-- I then added a field called weeks wait to the merged table

-- Part 2 - update difference
Update test.dbo.merged
Set test.dbo.merged.[Weeks_Wait]= DATEDIFF(WEEK,[Date_Start],[w/c])

-- part 3 - update totals
Update test.dbo.tbl_totals
Set [Total_Cases] = (Select sum(counter_val)
FROM   dbo.merged
Where   (test.dbo.merged.[Weeks_Wait] < 5) AND 
        (test.dbo.tbl_totals.[Week_Date] = test.dbo.merged.[Week_Date]) AND 
        (test.dbo.merged.[Weeks_Wait] between test.dbo.tbl_totals.[Week_From] and test.dbo.tbl_totals.[Week_To])
Group by test.dbo.merged.[Week_Date])
```